# Which description languague should I use for a webserver implemented using TidHttpServer?

Tags: web-services, delphi, rest, indy

I am using Delphi XE2 Update 4 Indy 10

I have a webservice implemented with idHttpServer that answers to traditional Http Get requests where I only interact with the variables retrieved from the URI.

This webserver have many other funcions already built in for local area network, etc. So I am considering to make it better than moving to a new platform.

The number of concurrent acesses are very low: max of 5 per time. The webservice retrieves data from a SQL server and answer with JSON.

I want to rewrite the services offering of this server in a such way that can be described and retrieved. Pretty much like DCOM Iunknown and Idispatch capabilities. I dont need it to be a public full implemented language like WSDL.

For me the RESTful style for the architecture is closer of what I have than anything related to SOAP.

I read a little that datasnap has an Indy core option and can do RESTful however I do not want to use Apache or IIS, I want to be a regular Windows application. I heard too many bad things about DataSnap...

I have read about AtomPub and RSDL, I dont know about others, but I need that there is some code on delphi to start using it.

My question: which description language should I use that I can find component/example to quickly start using it with my idHttpServer Server?

Comment: Another (not widely supported) standard is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Application_Description_Language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *description language* of your service may be the Delphi `interface` itself. Since you do not need to publish it, it makes it a safe and easy solution.

Considering your request:

> I want to rewrite the services offering of this server in a such way
>   that can be described and retrieved. Pretty much like DCOM Iunknown
>   and Idispatch capabilities. I dont need it to be a public full
>   implemented language like WSDL.

You may consider using our Open Source *mORMot* [interface-based services](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2012/03/07/Interface-based-services) for publishing and consuming your services.

They are using JSON over HTTP and REST, and almost all is automated. You only need to define your services with plain `interface`s which [will be used as service contracts](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2012/03/07/Defining-a-data-contract):

```
type
  ICalculator = interface(IInvokable)
    ['{9A60C8ED-CEB2-4E09-87D4-4A16F496E5FE}']
    /// add two signed 32 bit integers
    function Add(n1,n2: integer): integer;
  end;
```

Then [on the server side, you implement it as a regular Delphi class](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2012/03/07/Server-side):

```
type
  TServiceCalculator = class(TInterfacedObject, ICalculator)
  public
    function Add(n1,n2: integer): integer;
  end;

function TServiceCalculator.Add(n1, n2: integer): integer;
begin
  result := n1+n2;
end;

 Server.ServiceRegister(TServiceCalculator,[TypeInfo(ICalculator)],sicShared);
```

And [you consume the services on the client side](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2012/03/07/Using-services-on-the-Client-or-Server-sides) with no need of generating any wrapper:

```
var I: ICalculator;
begin
  if Client.Services['Calculator'].Get(I)) then
    result := I.Add(10,20);
end;
```

*mORMot* servers are stand-alone by design (no need of IIS or Apache), and you can run them as applications or services. You have additional features like security, authentication or session handling, with pretty good performance. Working from Delphi 6 to XE4, targeting Win32 and Win64 platforms.

*PS:*

You can even is you set `TServiceContainerServer.PublishSignature := true` and use the `_signature_` pseudo-method to retrieve a simple JSON signature:

```
[
    {
    "contract":"Calculator",
    "implementation":"shared",
    "methods":
        [
            {
            "method":"Add",
            "arguments":
                [
                    {"argument":"Self","direction":"in","type":"self"},
                    {"argument":"n1","direction":"in","type":"integer"},
                    {"argument":"n2","direction":"in","type":"integer"},
                    {"argument":"Result","direction":"out","type":"integer"}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Seems to be very interesting! However my question would be related to the client side in this case: it seems to be almost transparent for delphi based clients, how about android clients? Again, it will be my written clients, not public available. My question was focused on the server side, however to consider your answer I need that java can access that easily, and even better, the concept can be easy enought to be implemented on b4a, a vb-like language that generates java. Then I can implement the client side of this protocol.

Comment: @eelias There is no official Java client implementation yet (since we did not need it internally), only JavaScript code (in addition to native Delphi clients). But it could be very easy to consume mORMot services from Java, since it uses [a simple and documented REST scheme](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2012/03/07/Interface-based-services-implementation-details). You can even retrieve the methods signature as JSON (some kind of simple WSDL) - I updated my answer.

Comment: Very impressive! One last question to give a try on this server, is this a library that I can use on my already implemented server (of course some changes may happen) or is it a full server that I need to use as it is.

Comment: You can have several servers co-existing in the same exe. It won't use  Indy server, but direct access to the high-performance http.sys kernel-mode server (i.e. the same low level layer than IIS). It gives much better performances than Indy, and it allows URI-level registration (i.e. not only reserve one HTTP port to a server, but one URI pattern for a given port: you can even share the same port and root URI with IIS on the same PC).